# Plot three functions that share x-values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

How should I plot three different averages sharing x-axis.

My attempt with errorbars showing also standard deviation doesn't let me insert more than one "score", resulting in a single line plot

This is what I did currently

```
    times_alg_1_sparse = times_alg1['Sparse']
    avg_alg1_50_sparse, std_alg1_50_sparse = extract_statistics(times_alg_1_sparse.iloc[0])
    avg_alg1_200_sparse, std_alg1_200_sparse = extract_statistics(times_alg_1_sparse.iloc[1])
    avg_alg1_600_sparse, std_alg1_600_sparse = extract_statistics(times_alg_1_sparse.iloc[2])
    x = np.array(times_alg_1_sparse.index)
    y = np.array([avg_alg1_50_sparse*1000, avg_alg1_200_sparse*1000, avg_alg1_600_sparse*1000])
    e = np.array([std_alg1_50_sparse*1000, std_alg1_200_sparse*1000, std_alg1_600_sparse*1000])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.errorbar(x, y, e, mfc='red', linestyle='solid', marker='^', color='red')
    plt.ylim(0)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to call your plot function any times you want with different values.

I suppose your `avg` and `std` vectors have the same size, because they are output of the same function `extract_statistics`. You may have a problem with your vector `x`. Maybe the size of this vector does not match the size of `avg` and `std` vectors.

In the following solution we have three pairs of vectors `avg` and `std`: 50, 200, 600. We combine the 3 vectors in one vector `y` and `e`. So, in each iteration of the following `for` loop, we use the same vector `x` for the 3 different indexes from the vectors `y` and `e`. For this to work, we suppose the vector `x` and each element of `y` and `e` have the same size.

When we call something like `y[:,0]`, for example, we are slicing the vector `y` and getting all the values of the first column of this vector.

```py
times_alg_1_sparse = times_alg1['Sparse']

avg_alg1_50_sparse, std_alg1_50_sparse = extract_statistics(times_alg_1_sparse.iloc[0])
avg_alg1_200_sparse, std_alg1_200_sparse = extract_statistics(times_alg_1_sparse.iloc[1])
avg_alg1_600_sparse, std_alg1_600_sparse = extract_statistics(times_alg_1_sparse.iloc[2])

x = np.array(times_alg_1_sparse.index)
y = np.array([avg_alg1_50_sparse*1000, avg_alg1_200_sparse*1000, avg_alg1_600_sparse*1000])
e = np.array([std_alg1_50_sparse*1000, std_alg1_200_sparse*1000, std_alg1_600_sparse*1000])

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']    

for k in range(3):
    plt.errorbar(x, y[:,k], e[:,k], mfc=colors[k], linestyle='solid', marker='^', color=colors[k])

plt.ylim(0)
plt.show()
```

You are trying to use `subplots`. What is indicated when you want to plot, in the same figure, more than one graph.

Comment: Thank you for replying, this is my goal but I can't apply what you suggested me due to: IndexError: too many indices for array
This error regards the plt.errorbar, which parameter could have been raise it?

Comment: It should regard the arrays y[:,k] and e[:,k] 
How are they supposed to be built?

Comment: I don't know exactly your function `extract_statistics` works, but probably it is generating vectors with different sizes, while all your vectors must have the same. I'll edit my answer so as to explain better.